# Tkinter: How and best practice to access function outside frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a small GUI with tkinter, for which the main windows contains several "custom" widgets (frames with several buttons, etc).

To try and not bloat the `__init__()` of my main window, I created different classes that inherit from Frame, and in their `__init__()` I add the different elements such as buttons, etc. A sketch of the architecture is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.upframe= PicFrame(self)
        self.downframe=ButtonFrame(self)
        ...

    def manipulate_picframe(self):
        pass
```

Now in this example `PicFrame` and `ButtonFrame` would be two classes that inherit from `Frame`, and say the first one has a canvas and a label, and the other has two buttons.
Now my question is, when a button in `ButtonFrame` is clicked, I would like to (for example) draw a circle on the canvas of `PicFrame`. Now with the architecture above, the only way I see how to do that is to pass a reference of the function `manipulate_picframe()` to `ButtonFrame`, and use that.

The other way would be of course to not define the classes `PicFrame` and `ButtonFrame`, and do everything inside `MainWindow`, but I feel this would be much less readable.

What is the best practice in this case? Is there another way besides the two ways I suggested to solve this problem?

Comment: You passed `self` to your Frame objects; presumably they saved it in an instance variable, I will assume it's something like `self.parent`.  You can then use `self.parent.manipulate_picframe()` to call the method of the MainWindow object.

Comment: And yes, putting everything inside `MainWindow` _would_ be much less readable, aside from bad practice. It's good you're using separate classes for your custom widgets; it makes the code cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: @Jasonharper, that is true, I never considered saving that as an instance ! That sounds like a nice solution. What I had finally wind up doing was passing self.upframe as an attribute to ButtonFrame, which worked in this case, as I could define "manipulate_picframe" directly inside ButtonFrame. I guess both solutions are very similar !